# How to tightly link the Images/files stored on the firebase storage to the firestore fields?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm developing an android app. In that app, I upload the images to the firebase storage and I'll store the image/file URLs to the Firestore document fields.
My question is if I want to Migrate the database to other project does the URLs are still valid?
or Tell me how to tightly link the images/files in the firebase storage with its URLs stored on the fields.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, they will be valid, because the `URL` of a file will be same, a simple way to check to open url in the browser it will show u the image, means its valid

Comment: ok. But the URLs will points to my old database right?

Comment: your file url will never point to the `database` it will point to `storage` and changing `database` won't effect

Comment: No. What I'm asking is, My URLs in the firestore document field will points to the images//files on the old firebase storage right?

Comment: if its in the same project then right, and i dont think its the right approach, when you upload a file to storage, `firebase` gives you a `downloadUrl` of a file store the `url` to your db, it will same everywhere

Comment: Okay! Thanks for ur reply

Comment: please check my answer below, i have added some details there

Answer (score 3):

URLs pointing to files in Cloud Storage are not related to the location where they're stored.  If you store a URL to a file in Cloud Storage, that is valid for as long as the file exitsts in Cloud Storage (for signed URLs created by the admin SDK, until the specified expiration).

You can store that URL anywhere.  The location where it's stored has no bearing on its validity within the Cloud Storage product.  You can delete that URL from wherever it's stored, and the file will continue to exist in Cloud Storage.  You would have to delete that file from Cloud Storage in order to invalidate that URL (or manually revoke it).

Comment: Doug, then thats mean if I change the location from one folder to another within the same database in that case it will be no longer an valid url, right?

Comment: @RodParedes You can't actually change the location of a file in storage.  You can only copy it to the new location then delete the original.  Any sort of "move" operation is actually just doing this for you.  It will be a completely different object at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The **URL** of a firebase file doesn't point to `firebase` `database`, it points to specific file in the location, the best way to utilize this, is to store the `downloadUrl` in your db.

So when ever you will access that `URL` it will point to same `File` in the storage, you can even test this from console, in `storage -> click upload -> upload a file -> click on a file -> click on fileLocation -> Download Url` it will have the URL of a file.

Hope this clears your confusion.